# I want to know how to use Xcode properly for C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I made an Xcode project. Like this:
Mac OS X -> Application -> Command Line Tool
I chose C++
And then I saved it in a folder.

Now I opened it in Xcode, there is a file named main.cpp under the project name title, so I opened that.

So main.cpp contains (location: Desktop/CPP/learn/learn/main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now I click on File > New File and I selected C++ file without header, I named it main1.cpp

So that main1.cpp now just has

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I replaced that and made main1.cpp to

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "MAIN1DOTCPP!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then I ran main1.cpp, And the out put was "Hello World", I have been trying to get the output of the second file, That is "MAIN1DOTCPP" for like 2 hours now, Can someone please help?

Comment: You can only have one function named `main` in your program. You should never call it yourself. Even though they're in different source files, they are part of the same project.

Comment: So how do you have multiple practice files with different "main"'s? Is it even possible? Making new projects every time will be an insensitive thing to do. right?

Comment: You generally wind up with one project and multiple output targets, each target containing only one main or many very small projects each with only one main calling one big project that builds a library used by the small projects. Go with the model that best fits how you work. Since you are starting out and don't know how you work best, go with multiple projects,no library project, and a lot of duplication of common files across the many projects. It will reduce your learning curve.